# Tensorflow - Weight Noise Regularization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, noise

I'm trying to implement weight noise regularization like Alex Graves made in his PhD Thesis, but I have several issues in how I should implement that. The algorithm should look like

```c
 while stopping criteria not met do
   Randomize training set order
   for each example in the training set do
     Add zero mean Gaussian Noise to weights
     Run forward and backward pass to calculate the gradient
     Restore original weights
     Update weights with gradient descent algorithm
```

Could anyone shed some light?

**Edit 09/16/16**

Here is my code:

```python
# e.g: log filter bank or MFCC features
# Has size [batch_size, max_stepsize, num_features], but the
# batch_size and max_stepsize can vary along each step
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, num_features])

# Here we use sparse_placeholder that will generate a
# SparseTensor required by ctc_loss op.
targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)

# 1d array of size [batch_size]
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

# Defining the cell
# Can be:
#   tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell
#   tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)

# Stacking rnn cells
stack = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers,
                                    state_is_tuple=True)

# The second output is the last state and we will no use that
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)

shape = tf.shape(inputs)
batch_s, max_timesteps = shape[0], shape[1]

# Reshaping to apply the same weights over the timesteps
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, num_hidden])

# Truncated normal with mean 0 and stdev=0.1
# Tip: Try another initialization
# see https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#initializers
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden,
                                     num_classes],
                                    stddev=0.1))
# Zero initialization
# Tip: Is tf.zeros_initializer the same?
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[num_classes]))

# Doing the affine projection
logits = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b

# Reshaping back to the original shape
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_s, -1, num_classes])

# Time major
logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))

loss = tf.contrib.ctc.ctc_loss(logits, targets, seq_len)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(initial_learning_rate,
                                       0.9).minimize(cost)

# Option 2: tf.contrib.ctc.ctc_beam_search_decoder
# (it's slower but you'll get better results)
decoded, log_prob = tf.contrib.ctc.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, seq_len)

# Inaccuracy: label error rate
ler = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(decoded[0], tf.int32),
                                      targets))
```

**Edit 09/27/16**

I realized that I must change my optimizer in order to add noise weight regularizer. But, I have no idea how to insert this on my code.

```python
    variables = tf.trainable_variables()

    with tf.variable_scope(self.name or "OptimizeLoss", [loss, global_step]):

        update_ops = set(ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))

        # Make sure update ops are ran before computing loss.
        if update_ops:
            loss = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(list(update_ops), loss)

        add_noise_ops = [tf.no_op()]
        if self.weights_noise_scale is not None:
            add_noise_ops, remove_noise_ops = self._noise_ops(variables, self.weights_noise_scale)

            # Make sure add noise to weights before computing loss.
            loss = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(add_noise_ops, loss)


        # Compute gradients.
        gradients = self._opt.compute_gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=self.colocate_gradients_with_ops)

        # Optionally add gradient noise.
        if self.gradient_noise_scale is not None:
            gradients = self._add_scaled_noise_to_gradients(gradients, self.gradient_noise_scale)

        # Optionally clip gradients by global norm.
        if self.clip_gradients_by_global_norm is not None:
            gradients = self._clip_gradients_by_global_norm(gradients, self.clip_gradients_by_global_norm)

        # Optionally clip gradients by value.
        if self.clip_gradients_by_value is not None:
            gradients = self._clip_gradients_by_value(gradients, self.clip_gradients_by_value)

        # Optionally clip gradients by norm.
        if self.clip_gradients_by_norm is not None:
            gradients = self._clip_gradients_by_norm(gradients, self.clip_gradients_by_norm)

        self._grads = [g[0] for g in gradients]
        self._vars = [g[1] for g in gradients]

        # Create gradient updates.
        # Make sure that the noise of weights will be removed before the  gradient update rule
        grad_updates = self._opt.apply_gradients(gradients,
                                               global_step=global_step,
                                               name="train")


        # Ensure the train_tensor computes grad_updates.
        train_tensor = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([grad_updates], loss)
```

Could anyone shed some light on me?
Thanks :)

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to add the noise? Tensorflow offers a Gaussian noise function: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#random_normal

Comment: I know, but i have no clue how to add the algorithm above on Tensorflow.

Comment: Do you understand how to build and train the tensorflow model without the weight noise regularization?

Comment: Yes, I've already had a working model.

Answer (score 1):

To solve that I would build 2 graphs: one for training and another for evaluation. The latter won't sum the noise to the weights. To sum a random noise to the weights, you can just do:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden,
                                     num_classes],
                                    stddev=0.1))
noise = tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, num_classes],
                            stddev=0.001))
W = W + noise
```

The tensor `tf.truncated_normal` will add a small amount of random noise to your weights.